# How to remove wildcard character in tkinter text?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, wildcard

I want to remove every text inside < >.
I used to replace('<*>',' ')  but it does not remove them at all.

For example, my text is **`"<a/ddff>Nitin Hardeniya - 2015 - ‎Computers"`**
I want it to turn into **`"Nitin Hardeniya - 2015 - ‎Computers"`**.

Please advise me on how should I correct my code.

Here is code:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
text = root.clipboard_get()
def onclick():
    text_widget.delete("1.0", "end")   
    text_widget.insert(tk.END, text.replace('<*>',' '))   

root = tk.Tk()
text_widget = tk.Text(root)
text_widget.insert(tk.END, text)  #inserting the data in the text widget
text_widget.pack()

button = tk.Button(root, text = "Press me!", command = onclick)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Read [Why are multiple instances of Tk discouraged?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48045508/7414759)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a regular expression for such matching. the `<*>` in your line:
`text.replace('<*>',' ')` is not a regular expression it is a strict match (see `replace` function documentation)

A way of doing it is

```
def onclick():
    original = text_widget.get("1.0", "end")   
    pattern = re.compile(r'(<[^<>]+>)')
    fixed= pattern.sub(r" ", original )
    text_widget.delete("1.0", "end")   
    text_widget.insert(tk.END, fixed)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for telling me. however fixed= pattern.sub(r" ", original ) is not used.  And it does not work.

Comment: Sorry replace orignal by fixed in the tkinter entry.

Comment: what does it exactly mean? I'm new to tkinter.

Comment: Hello I updated the regexp based on the sample you hadded in the question